# Form Submission to Self (PHP)

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a dynamically built survey page that gets relevant questions and answers from the database and generates the form. I have also set up a check to make sure that the "survey_id" from the URL exists in the table (if not, redirect to index.php), and that it is a valid number and not an alphabet.

Originally, I had set the form submit to send the data to another php file and process it there. However, I have need to handle the data in the same page. I attempted to make a few changes, however -

1) Upon submit, the page redirects to index.php since the "survey_id" URL element is missing.
2) If I target the form submit to "survey_frontend.php?survey_id=currentID", the form just reloads and there is no change.

**The code I believe would be wholly relevant in this case, and hence too big to post here. The code can be found here :** http://codepad.org/7GSkHkL2

At the moment I am just trying to get the Echo "Congrats" statement to work upon submit, which is not happening.

Comment: What does `print_r($_POST);` returns?

Comment: Why don't you send surveyID on form submit?

Comment: Sending SurveyID on form submit would just reprint the entire form all over again wouldn't it? Ideally I want the form to disappear and just a message along the lines of "Thank you for your time" or something

Comment: @RoySchoep - That returns the answers to each of the questions (Just tried it)

Comment: Oh sure I post a complex problem and immediately its flagged down -_- Beautiful. If I could show you the sheer amount of research I put into this problem... meh nvm.

Comment: However, you can manage that. You can act according to your post type. If it is POST do action A, or else do action B

Comment: @cubuzoa Could you explain that in a bit more detail please? :) That is exactly what I need at the moment, but I am a beginner in php and don't fully understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_POST[] access form controls through their names, which is given through the name attribute. Currently your code cannot detect the submit button, and thus your page will never get to congratulate anyone.
Give your button a name, and it will shine with its presence!

```
<input type="submit" **name="submit"** value="Submit!" />
```

Comment: You are a GOD!! Wow I never saw that coming. Thank you SO much for solving that issue, it was eating my brains out!

Answer (score 1):

Here a summary what I try to explain;

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
      // do your job here 
      die("<span class='success'>Your form submitted!</span>");

} else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET'){
      // get your values from db and check survey id
      if ($_GET["surveyID"] != $id_from_db) {
        $URL="/index.php";
        header ("Location: $URL");
      } else {
          // If you have validation, do it here. Do not directly use it on html form
      }
} else {
      die("<span class='success'>Operation not supported!</span>");
}

// Your html
```